# Generating random passwords with shell on server deployment

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to generate random and secure passwords to my various configuration files and settings on the fly when I run my automated deployment script. I want them to be generated, shown to the user, used as part of the deployment and then discarded.

This is what I was going with:

```
# FUNCTION TO GENERATE A RANDOM STRING
function randpass() {
  [ "$2" == "0" ] && CHAR="[:alnum:]" || CHAR="[:graph:]"
    cat /dev/urandom | tr -cd "$CHAR" | head -c ${1:-32}
    echo
}

$NOW = $(date +"%m-%d-%Y") || echo ="Time = $now"
$APPKEY = randpass(20) || echo "Secret key = $APPKEY"
read -p "Copied down?" -n1 -s
```

1. Is this a bad approach?
2. Is this secure?
3. Will the passwords be stored as variables after deployment has finished?

I'm new to shell and linux administration so any help is appreciated.

James

Comment: I don't see it necessary to downvote this. Yes, it's not really topical and probably *should* be closed as opinion-based, but the question is well-put.

Comment: Really, only the first question is asking for an opinion. The second question is a little underspecified. The third question seems fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If the user has to copy the password to paper, that paper is the new weakpoint. Whether or not that is a tolerable approach depends on your application and the environment it is used in. (Can the user change the password to something he does *not* need to write down? Is the user writing it down the user typing it in, or will that paper be passed around, or even {shudder} be attached to a monitor via post-it?)

2) Aside from potential bugs in `randpass()` (which I haven't gone over in detail), you are *displaying* the password, so anyone standing beside the user running the deployment will see it as well. Moreover, is the person running the deployment script the same user as the one that will use the application (and needing the password)?

You see from 1) and 2) above that, regardless of how "secure" the password is, it's the *protocol* that matters as well, to the point that how `randpass()` actually comes up with the password is almost irrelevant.

A common approach would be to provide a *initial* password (secure or not is a different matter), then allow a (very) short grace period in which the user can change that password to one of his liking, and if it is not changed in that period, locking the account. (This is basically what `passwd --expire --inactive 1` does.)

Alternatively, let the user *type in* the password instead of confronting him with a random sequence of characters (because 1) above). Set the terminal to no-echo via `read -s` (so the password does not appear on screen as typed), and let him repeat the password to rule out typos. Because, why make him *change* your random password to something else when you can just ask him to give you the password to begin with?

3) No. Once the script finishes, any variables that were set are gone, unless you explicitly stored them somewhere.

That last one is actually the only thing that can be answered with any certainty, which is why I'm now going to vote-for-close. ;-)

Comment: @JamesWillson: Edited some more into it, as this didn't get closed as fast as I expected. ;-)

Comment: `3)` is not certain.  There's always a chance it could be swapped to disk.

Comment: @JohnB: ...or the system could have been hardened by encrypting swap, or disabling swap completely. You've got to make a cut-off between paranoia and sanity somewhere. ;-)